# Why can't this C++ template code be compiled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, compilation

This is some sample code copied from [The C++ Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language) chapter 17 as below. When I compile it with Visual Studio 2008, it keeps giving me this error:
`warning C4346: 'HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::mapped_type' : dependent name is not a type
1>        prefix with 'typename' to indicate a type`

Does anyone have any idea about this? 
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using std::iterator;

template<class Key, class T, class H= Hash<Key>, class EQ = equal_to<Key>, class A = allocator<pair<const Key, T>>>
class HashMap{
public:
    typedef Key key_type;
    typedef T mapped_type;
    typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;
    typedef typename A::size_type size_type;
    typedef H Hasher;
    typedef EQ key_equal;

    HashMap(const T& dv=T(), size_type n = 101, const H& hf = H(), const EQ& = EQ()):
            :default_value(dv), b(n), no_of_erased(0), hash(hf), eq(e){
        set_load();
        v.reserve(max_load*b.size());
    }
    template<class In> HashMap(In first, In last,
        const T& dv=T(), size_type n=101, const H& hf=H(), const EQ& = EQ());

    void set_load(float m=0.7, float g=1.6){
        max_load = m;
        grow = g;
    }
    mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& k);

    void resize(size_type n);
    void erase(iterator position);
    size_type size() const { return v.size() - no_of_erased;}
    size_type bucket_count() const { return b.size();}
    Hasher hash_fun() const { return hash;}
    key_equal key_eq() const { return eq;}

private:
    struct Entry{
        key_type key;
        mapped_type val;
        bool erased;
        Entry* next;
        Entry(key_type k, mapped_type v, Entry* n):
            key(k),val(v),erased(false),next(n) {}
    };

    vector<Entry> v;
    vector<Entry*> b;

    float max_load;
    float grow;
    size_type no_of_erased;
    Hasher hash;
    key_equal eq;

    const T default_value;

};


template<class Key, class T, class H=Hash<Key>, class EQ=equal_to<Key>, class A=allocator<pair<const Key,T>>> 
HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::mapped_type & HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::operator [](const HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::key_type& k){
    size_type i = hash(k)%b.size();

    for(Entry* p=b[i]; p; p=p->next){
        if(eq(k, p->key)){
            if(p->erased){
                p->erased = false;
                no_of_erased--;
                return p->val=default_value;
            }
            return p->val;
        }
    }

    if(size_type(b.size()*max_load) <= v.size()){
        resize(b.size()*grow);
        return operator[](k);
    }

    v.push_back(Entry(k,default_value,b[i]));
    b[i] = &v.back();

    return b[i]->val;
}

template<class Key, class T, class H=Hash<Key>, class EQ=equal_to<Key>, class A=allocator<pair<const Key,T>>> 
void HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::resize(size_type s){
    size_type i = v.size();
    while(no_of_erased){
        if(v[--i].erased){
            v.erase(&v[i]);
            --no_of_erased;
        }
    }

    if(s<=b.size())
        return;
    b.resize(s);
    fill(b.begin(),b.end(),0);
    v.reserve(s*max_load);

    for(size_type i=0;i<v.size(); i++){
        size_type ii = hash(v[i].key)%b.size();
        v[i].next = b[ii];
        b[ii] = &v[i];
    }
}

template<class Key, class T, class H=Hash<Key>, class EQ=equal_to<Key>, class A=allocator<pair<const Key,T>>>
void HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::erase(iterator p){
        if(p->erased == false) no_of_erased++;
        p->erased = true;
}


int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? If the example from a well-known book is giving a warning from well-known compiler, this seems like a good question for a learner to ask.

Comment: @ArtB: downvote link says "The question does not show any research effort". At least for that, since the error clearly says what to do to solve it. If the OP wanted to know why this is needed then the part of the downvote link saying "it is unclear" matches.

Comment: @PlasmaHH But if you are a beginner, its really hard to do research. The fact that they are taking code from "The C++ Programming Language" already shows they are doing research. When a question is entry-level or the user is beginner it is difficult to do much meaningful research. This is different than post ~300 lines, of code and saying "something here is broke, fix it for me"

Comment: @ArtB: For me it reads "this is is code, it doesnt compile, I didnt bother to read the error message, you do it for me".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::mapped_type & HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::operator []
```

to

```
typename HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::mapped_type & HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::operator []
```

as your error already suggests. The compiler cannot deduce on it's own that `mapped_type` is a `typedef` inside a class template.

Comment: Pieter, Thank you very much for your answer! It really works after I added 'typename'.
But there's another error:
error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template
It seems the function definitions can't use template arguments like this:
template<class Key, class T, class H=Hash<Key>, 
    class EQ=equal_to<Key>, class A=allocator<pair<const Key,T>>> 
typename HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::mapped_type & HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::operator [](const typename HashMap<Key,T,H,EQ,A>::key_type & k)

Do you have any solutions? 
Thank you again!

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks for reminder.

And thanks to Pieter, I've worked it out.